# Installing AJAX Tool Kit in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-ajax

I have recently tried to add an Ajax Web Form to a project, using VS Ultimate 2013, but I just couldn't do it. There is no AJAX Web Form option like in VS 2010.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about MVC AjaxExtensions.BeginForm?

Comment: do you mean you cannot find AJAX took kit in visual studio ?

Comment: Gosha, I need the AJAX took kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download AJAX Took Kit from this website [`AJAXToolKit`](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Once you have downloaded it extract the file and there will be a "ajaxtoolkit.dll" file .

Go to Visual Studio --> `Tool box window` --> Right Click --> Add Tab..

[image]

Give this tab a name like `"AJAXToolKit"`.

Once the tab has been created right click the tab again and go to `Choose Items...`

[image]

AT this point the following pop-up window will show:

[image]

Click on the `Browse` button and navigate to the file you downloaded earlier on and select the `AJAXControlToolKit.dll` file and click `OK` . and you are good to go